# php date difference calculation adding additional days

Tags: php, datetime, diff

Trying to display difference between two dates in PHP.

```
<?php
    $date1 = new DateTime("2022-03-01");
    $date2 = new DateTime("2022-04-01");
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    echo $interval->days;
    echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days "; 
?>
```

I am getting result as:-

> 31difference 0 years, 1 months, 3 days

`$interval->days` result is correct, but why having `$interval->d` as 3 when its just a month difference?

Comment: Looks like the `d` always trims off the last integer, not sure why... just use `days` though and you should be fine, right?

Comment: You should get normally : 
31difference 0 years, 1 months, 0 days - something might wrong with DateTime function :xd

Comment: @user3783243 `days` I just displayed for reference, I actually need difference in year `(y)` , month `(m)`, days `(d)`

Comment: *Looks like the `d` always trims off the last integer, not sure why...* you mean it picks 3 from `days`? @user3783243

Comment: It is loosing the `1` for some reason. There are 31 days difference. If you expand to +100 days you get the 2 leading integers but third missing.

Comment: @user3783243 test this:- `$date1 = new DateTime("2022-07-01"); $date2 = new DateTime("2022-09-01");`

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? It works correctly for me (shows "...0 days") with PHP 7.4.6 and 5.6.32.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
<?php
    $date1 =DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2022-03-01");
    $date2 =DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2022-04-01");
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    echo $interval->days;
    echo " \ndifference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days "; 
?>
```

Comment: agreed, this solved the issue, but do you know why we need to again format? +1

Comment: Looks like some bug in the DateTime constructor. It works properly for some timezones like America eg: "America/Sitka" but fails for asian timezones "Asia/Dubai".   By default it will be using the default timezone set in the php.ini "date.timezone" settings when the second parameter is not passed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug, that depends on the timezone and hour.

With UTC timezone, it is OK :

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2022-03-01 00:00", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$date2 = new DateTime("2022-04-01 00:00", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
```

> difference 0 years, 1 months, 0 days

With Europe/Berlin timezone at midnight, we have the 3 days offset :

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2022-03-01 00:00", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$date2 = new DateTime("2022-04-01 00:00", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
```

> difference 0 years, 1 months, 3 days

At 01:00 in the morning, it is kind of OK : 0 month but 31 days

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2022-03-01 01:00", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$date2 = new DateTime("2022-04-01 01:00", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
```

> 0 years, 0 months, 31 days

At 12:00, everything is right again: 1 month

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2022-03-01 12:00", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$date2 = new DateTime("2022-04-01 12:00", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
```

> 0 years, 1 months, 0 days